# SGS2 Replace preinstalled apps in Custom ROM

Tags: custom-roms

Is is possible to change / modify the custom ROM you're about to install on your rooted Galaxy S2 (9100)?

Usually, I would install [CyanogenMod 10 Nightly build](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=nightly&device=i9100). Then, I'd install [GAPPS (google apps)](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Latest_Version#Google_Apps). Lastly, I'd restart and it would work.

Now, what I want to do is to replace a default CM (CyanogenMod) apps (SMS, Contact manager/Call manager) with those included in [JB 4.1.2 (leaked version)](http://galaxys2root.com/galaxy-s2-roms/leaked-official-android-4-1-2-rom-with-root-for-galaxy-s2-gt-i9100/).

Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance for any info and suggestions.

**UPDATED POST**

[Here is a pic of apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haznD.jpg) difference in icons (on left CM10, onright JB)
[And here is a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpgDo.jpg) of apps in `system/app/` of those versions

Comment: Are you certain it would work? JB leaked version and CM's own apps are slightly different in that the CM version would have extra dependencies on CM specific data, whereas the JB version leaked is more than likely to have Samsung bits in it (judging by the linky).. In a nutshell, it may work, may not (i.e. force close), 50|50 either way... to quote from the leaked version on the third linky, *The leaked Android 4.1.2 clearly shows that the official 4.1.2 Jelly Bean firmware will come with goodies like Galaxy S3 TouchWiz UX launcher, widgets, camera that allows stop and go, and some more.*

Comment: actually i'am not expert in these theory, so correct me if iam wrong. i tested the last custom rom "LionRom", and it comes with "Contact manager/Call app" like in Leaked JB, but with old SMS Manager app. Now i have CM10, but both with old Contact/Call and SMS app which i want to replace by the new one. The problem is that i can't find these LeakedJB apps :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're rooted within CM, its a matter of doing the following, provided you have read the following:

***Caveat Emptor:***

The Jellybean leaked apks are signed with the signature key used to generate the signed leaked ROM of JB, however, it may clash with CM's own signature key which is, and I'll guarantee, different, so may not work at all!

You are on your own from there onwards.

## -------------------------------------

- remounting the `/system` rewriteable as in `adb remount` to make it writeable
- replace the apk's concerned within `/system/app` by adb pushing the appropriate apks taken from JB, as in `adb push name_of_jb_apk.apk /system/app` (Repeat for each apk concerned) - *this will overwrite the apk's already residing in `/system/app`*
- remount the `/system` as read-only as in `adb remount`

Reboot, and go into clockworkmod recovery and clear the data/cache, the reason being is to remove the old cached data that was in use by the old apk's, and thus, minimize the chances of force closes within the relevant apks in question.

I will list the actual filenames for the apk's concerned:

- Sms, the filename is `Mms.apk`
- Contacts, there's two apks involved, `ContactsProvider.apk` and `Contacts.apk`
- Dialler, name is `Phone.apk`, now, beware, this may have a dependency on `TelephonyProvider.apk` also.

Whilst I have mentioned the actual apk's, I am therefore disclaiming any responsibility for anything that may happen on your handset as a result of replacing system apps.

Comment: i updated my question, can u look at the links ? because i can't find the similiar app for apps i want to replace (Mms.apk,Phone.apk, etc...)

Comment: Try GmsCore.apk (That's a *long* shot!) It could be dependent on another apk.....?!?!?!

Comment: will try that in a second... btw to be able to use adb in my windows7 command line, what should i install ?

Comment: Yes, see [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1474956) this will get you the basic adb tools necessary for it to run under windows 7.

Comment: Iam so noob that i can't do that. i successfully connected to device via command line, but when i call `adb remount` it just wont work, same for `adb push`

Comment: I did it in this order: `adb kill-server`, then `adb root` > `adb remount` and only after this order it becomes writable. But now, where to get these apps from JB and push it into my CM rom ?